# Why was Andor delayed to September 21?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, andor

In the most recent trailer for *Andor*, the upcoming series about Cassian Andor as a prequel to Rogue One, we were notified that the series has been delayed to a three-episode premiere on September 21. **Why was *Andor* delayed?**

Comment: Less competition (with its own stuff (She-Hulk) and external (GoT, LOTR)) and also so they could have a bigger premier it would appear. However, doesn't look like the reason has been officially explained as far as I can tell.

Comment: A number of news sites have offered different *possible* reasons, such as those already commented on, but since Disney has not given an official reason everything else is speculation.

Comment: I was hoping as well that it was to keep it further away from She-Hulk.  For a while there that had it down to a science - alternating a Marvel and Star Wars series, so the fans always had a reason to keep their subscriptions active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The show's main actor, Diego Luna explained in an interview that the delay was to allow the first three episodes to be released simultaneously rather than having fans wait three weeks for three single shows.

> When asked about the delay, Diego describes it as "great news,"
> although he appreciates that some fans might not agree.
>
> "Basically, the big idea behind the push was: how do we make sure
> audiences get to understand what the show will be about? What this
> show is bringing, and what we're aiming for? And how ambitious it is?"
>
> "To understand that, I think you need to be able to see three
> episodes," continues Luna. "That was a very smart move, to say, 'We
> want you to understand what the show is going to bring to you. If
> you're going to invest your time in our show, you need to understand
> the big game.'"
>
> <sub><sup>[Diego Luna explains why Andor's delay is actually "great news" for Star Wars fans](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a40989685/andor-diego-luna-delay/)</sup></sub>

No explanation has been given why this necessitated a *delay* (e.g. rather than just moving the show up three weeks) but I think we can assume that it's because the dates for the shows on Disney+ are planned years in advance to ensure a continual stream of new shows with no large gaps between. Moving the show up up three weeks would have meant that the next show along (Mandalorean Season 3 - Feb) would be starting with a three month gap rather than a two month gap, with the [*Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special*](https://www.marvel.com/tv-shows/guardians-of-the-galaxy-holiday-special/1) sitting in between.

Comment: And/or they needed the two weeks to get the visual effects finished.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Or so they could make the transitions less obvious to people who're binging the first three episodes back to back

Comment: Is it the first show on Disney+ where several of the first episodes are released simultaneously? I think episodes of Marvel TV shows have all been released one by one. I don't watch Star Wars shows.

Comment: @Taladris - Some shows have been 'dumped', where the entire series has been available instantly. Not recently though. They seem to be steadily relearning that serial viewing leads to better ratings

Comment: "They seem to be steadily relearning that serial viewing leads to better ratings" And longer subscriptions.

Comment: After watching the first three episodes, I can definitely confirm that it needed the first three episodes to pick up. Audience retention is the name of the game.